# Getting properties of list of instances

Tags: python

I need to use a list of instances properties inside a loop but I couldn't find a solution. The list is the following:

```
widths = 
[<__main__.MIZ_info instance at 0x7f6936fc7368>,
<__main__.MIZ_info instance at 0x7f6936ce6d40>,
<__main__.MIZ_info instance at 0x7f6936c4ca28>,
None,
<__main__.MIZ_info instance at 0x7f6936994998>,
<__main__.MIZ_info instance at 0x7f69368d69e0>,
<__main__.MIZ_info instance at 0x7f6936704638>,
None]
```

Now every instance has several properties (width.property1, width.property2, etc...) and I need to collect some of them inside a list. I tried the following without any success:

```
for n,en in enumerate(widths):
    list1.append(en.property1)
    list2.append(en.property2)
```

I have encountered:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'property1'
```

It looks such a simple problem but I am still struggling with it!
Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: I guess it's important to say that I can't modify the instances which are generated by a third party software used by others.

Comment: Are you *supposed* to have a bunch of Nones in your list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because there are `None` items in `widths` and `None` doesn't have a property `en.property1`. You fix this by checking for `None`s.

```
for n, en in enumerate(widths):
    if en is not None:
        list1.append(en.property1)
        list2.append(en.property2)
    else:
        # do something when en is None
```

Comment: That was it. I am currently looking for a cave so that I can live there the rest of my life in shame. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

check that `en` is not `None` before appending it's properties:

```
if en != None: #or if en: (equivalent if you don't expect anything else)
    list1.append(en.property1)
    list2.append(en.property2)
else: #if you want to have placeholders for those None values. If not, take this out
    list1.append(None)
    list2.append(None)
```

Or you can have a `try` block to catch exceptions:

```
try:
    list1.append(en.property1)
    list2.append(en.property2)
except AttributeError:
    #do what you need if en is None
```

Comment: That was it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The first line should be `if en is not None` (as indicated by the comment with `if en`).